# Loop to make sub lists on condition with python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a little code that creates a dictionary

```
result = {6: 4, 12: 5, 17: 4, 23: 5, 28: 4, 36: 7, 37: 0, 46: 8, 52: 5, 57: 4, 62: 4, 89: 26, 113: 23, 134: 20, 136: 1, 149: 12, 161: 11, 173: 11, 175: 1, 178: 2, 201: 22, 202: 0, 209: 6}
```

The keys are positions and values are the spacing between that characters.

I need to filter those values for spacing between 0 and 9 and output separate lists for stretches that are "continuous" with spacing between 0 and 9.

The code should run over every key, and check the following key; if the spacing is between 0 and 9 it should add the keys to a list and if the next one is greater then 9 it should close the list and start a new list and test again.

```
temp = []
jmax = 0
jmin = 9             
                
for i in range(0, len(result.keys())):
        j = i+1
        if j < len(result.keys()):
            key1 = list(result.keys())[i]
            key2 = list(result.keys())[j]
            var1 = key2 - key1
            if 0 <= var1 <= 9:
                temp.append(key1) if key1 not in temp else temp
                temp.append(key2) if key2 not in temp else temp    

print (temp)
```

I was able to filter but can figure out how to get a list of lists.
Does anybody have some idea how to get this to this?

Results should be:

```
[[6, 12, 17, 23, 28, 36, 37, 46, 52, 57, 62], 
[134, 136], 
[173, 175, 178], 
[201, 202, 209]]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is `134` in the output? Its spacing is 20. Also, `173` and `201`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it seems it's in the output because it's the start of sub-sequence where the spacing between each element of the sub-sequence is less than or equal to 9

Comment: I'm also not sure what the values in the dictionary are for because they aren't getting used, and don't line up with the differences between consecutive positions.

Comment: The point is that the code needs to be adapted for other spacing lengths.
Values of the dictionary are necessary for other purposes of the analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need another list to append to as you close each list sublist

```
temp = []
jmax = 0
jmin = 9
output = []

keys = list(result.keys())
                
for i in range(len(keys) - 1):
    j = i+1
    key1 = keys[i]
    key2 = keys[j]
    var1 = key2 - key1
    if 0 <= var1 <= 9:
        if key1 not in temp:
            temp.append(key1)
        temp.append(key2)
    else:
        if len(temp) > 0:
            output.append(temp)
        temp = []
            
if len(temp) > 0:            
    output.append(temp)

print (output)
```

Checking if key2 is already in temp is unnecessary since it can't be yet.

Since you're only using the key list anyway, you can just extract it from dictionary before hand. If you have access to the positions of characters as a list from the start and are using that to generate the dictionary, then generating the dictionary is unnecessary.